# How to create HTTP Session in Go

Tags: go, fasthttp

I am currently using fasthttp for sending my requests my question is, is there a way to have a persistent session? I need the cookies and data to stick.

`c := fasthttp.Client{ Name: "Add To Cart",}`

```
store, err := session.Start() // ?????
args := fasthttp.AcquireArgs()
defer fasthttp.ReleaseArgs(args)

args.Add("pid", sizepid)
args.Add("options", "[]")
args.Add("quantity", "1")

statusCode, body, err := c.Post(nil, "URL", args)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}`
```

Comment: Should I switch over to go-sessions? or can I continue to use fasthttp?

Comment: There's a session package for fasthttp: https://github.com/phachon/fasthttpsession . It's in the fasthttp readme and that package's readme has code examples.

Comment: How would I add it to something like this?? since I don't have the fasthttp.RequestCtx. I edited my question to include the code.

Comment: The `fasthttpsession` package seems to be intended for use with `fasthttp` as a server, not as a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on your question I think this is already clear to you, but just in case:* 
Sessions aren't started on the client, they are started on the server. The server checks to see if a specific cookie exists; if it does it resumes the session that the cookie identifies; if it doesn't it creates a new session and sends the identifier back to the client as a cookie. All the client needs to do is send the correct cookie to the server.

So, you need to read and write cookies. The `fasthttp.Client.Post()` interface doesn't allow you to do that. So instead of that nice interface, things become rather ugly.

You need to ask `fasthttp` for both a `Request` and `Response` object before you do the request. Once you've done the initial request, you need to either look all cookies, or read out a specific cookie. You can now use those values for your next request.

I've written a short example of how you would do this.

```golang
func main() {
    c := fasthttp.Client{}

    // Create a request
    req := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
    defer fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req)
    req.SetRequestURI(`https://www.google.com/`)

    // Create a response
    resp := fasthttp.AcquireResponse()
    defer fasthttp.ReleaseResponse(resp)

    // Execute the request, writing to the response object
    err := c.Do(req, resp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //  Loop over all cookies; usefull if you want to just send everything back on consecutive requests
    resp.Header.VisitAllCookie(func(key, value []byte) {
        log.Printf("Cookie %s: %s\n", key, value)
    })

    // Read a specific cookie
    nid := fasthttp.AcquireCookie()
    defer fasthttp.ReleaseCookie(nid)
    nid.SetKey(`NID`)
    if resp.Header.Cookie(nid) {
        log.Println("Value for NID Cookie: " + string(nid.Value()))

        // Create a second request and set the cookie from the first
        req2 := fasthttp.AcquireRequest()
        defer fasthttp.ReleaseRequest(req2)
        req2.SetRequestURI(`https://www.google.com/`)
        req2.Header.SetCookie(`NID`, string(nid.Value()))

        // Now you can execute this request again using c.Do() - don't forget to acquire a new Response!
    }
}
```

Note: you *can* chose to skip the `fasthttp.AcquireXXX()` and `defer fasthttp.ReleaseXXX(yyy)` steps - but that would negate much (maybe most) of the performance benefits over using standard `net/http`, so if you go that route maybe just ditch `fasthttp` all together.

Comment: How do I add all cookies to future request which is in another func??

Comment: Well, you could build a `map[string]string` that you fill inside `VisitAllCookie()` and pass that map to the other func (either explicitly as a parameter, or more implicitly by making the map a property on the struct that contains the func).